# Core Audio Driver not working

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, audio

I have been using Virtual DJ on my machine.  The setup is where I want audio to play over the headphones and use a USB sound card to play audio into my headphones so I can listen to music before I play it for everybody.

[image]

However, the last time I tried, I got an error message saying "Error in the sound driver of Core Audio.  Your sound card is probably not connected, or the settings are incorrect".

[image]

If I use the headphone by themselves, the USB sound card by itself, or my speakers by themselves, they all work individually.

How do I go about figuring out what's wrong here?

Comment: Just asking did you tried rebooting or killing the CoreAudio Drive ?

Comment: I have rebooted several times.  I do not know how to kill or reinstall the Core Audio driver.

Comment: You can kill it with `killall /usr/sbin/coreaudiod` in the terminal but rebooting almost does the same thing so it won't help you.

Comment: I tried `killall`.  The response is `No matching processes belonging to you were found`.  Is it that the service somehow is AWOL?

Comment: try `ps -e | grep core` If you don't see `coreaudiod` it means it's not running. That could a hint to your problem.

Comment: hmm.. the `coreaudiod` process exists, but it does not have my name under it. the owner is shown with `??`.  It shows up as `171 ??        36:28.58 /usr/sbin/coreaudiod`

Comment: `??` is not the owner but the `TTY`.

Comment: The coreaudiod process is not owned by your user so you'll need to use sudo: `sudo killall coreaudiod`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out!

Under Utilities, there is a MIDI setup.  This had stored a profile for my Virtual DJ pro software.

I deleted that profile, restarted my software, and the error went away.

Apparently, there was an invalid configuration saved that was causing the issue.  I wish I had saved screenshots of the profile so that we can actually see what the error was.

Answer (score 1):

When the USB sound card is plugged to the Mac, do you see it in System Profiler (from Apple Menu -> About this Mac -> More Info... -> System Report) as a USB device ?

If so, can you then see the audio device in System Preferences -> Sound -> Output ?
If not, would other USB devices work on the same USB port ?

Comment: I see it in the system profiler.  I cannot see it under System Preferences.  It is because the driver went bad?

Comment: CoreAudio is part of the OS, have you installed extra drivers ?

Comment: I guess the best way I can answer that is to say I have installed more software than comes in on the Mac out of the box.  I do not know if the software I have installed has installed any drivers.  How do I check that?

Answer (score 1):

i figured out how to end this problem. I closed VDJ, then opened application/utilities/audio midi setup. then delete the VDJ advanced setup. then re-open VDJ and it worked like a charm again.